# Find the extreme for priority function / alphabet order

Tags: algorithm, math

We have an array of elements `a1,a2,...aN` from an alphabet `E`. Assuming `|N| >> |E|`.

For each symbol of the alphabet we define an unique integer priority = `V(sym)`. Let's define `V{i} := V(symbol(ai))` for the simplicity.

How can I find the priority function V for which:

```
Count(i)->MAX | V{i} < V{i+1}
```

In other words, I need to find the priorities / permutation of the alphabet for which the number of positions `i`, satisfying the condition `V{i}<V{i+1}`, is maximum.

**Edit-1:** Please, read carefully. I'm given an array `ai` and the task is to produce a function `V`. It's **not** about sorting the input array with a priority function.

**Edit-2: Example**

`E = {a,b,c}; A = 'abcab$';` (here $ = artificial termination symbol, V{$}=+infinity)

One of the optimal priority functions is: `V{a}=1,V{b}=2,V{c}=3`, which gives us the following signs between array elements: `a<b<c>a<b<$`, resulting in 4 '<' signs of 5 total.

Comment: You mean sorting with a non-standard compare function?

Comment: I didn't look at the problem from the side of sorting the alphabet with a custom priority function. When you swap two nearby priority values, you have all other priorities untouched, so I think that side of a problem (sorting) is adequate.

Comment: So if your alphabet is {a,b,c} and your sequence is (a,b,c,b,a) two optimal solution functions would be V={a=>1,b=>2,c=>3} and V={a=>3,b=>2,c=>1}. The maximum value of Count(i) is |E|-1. Correct?

Comment: @xan. I added an example to the question, which is a bit better than yours, because the optimal priority function makes better results than any other. Your example looks to be correct, just with a small note that `Count(i)` has nothing to do with `|E|`.

Comment: How big can |E| be? (Or min(N, |E|) to be precise.) This is important in deciding which algorithms would be feasible.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR. Good question! I've added the relation between N and E to the problem description (|N|>>|E|). To be precise, I'm working with files on the input as byte arrays, so |E|<256, |N| is arbitrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>If elements could not have tied priorities, this would be trivial.  Just sort by priority.  But you can have equal priorities.</strike>

I would first sort the alphabet by priority.  Then I'd extract the longest rising subsequence.  That is the start of your answer.  Extract the longest rising subsequence from what remains.  Append that to your answer.  Repeat the extraction process until the entire alphabet has been extracted.

I believe that this gives an optimal result, but I haven't tried to prove it.  If it is not perfectly optimal, it still will be pretty good.

Now that I think I understand the problem, I can tell you that there is no good algorithm to solve it.

To see this let us first construct a directed graph whose vertices are your elements, and whose edges indicate how many times one element immediately preceeded another.  You can create a priority function by dropping enough edges to get a directed acyclic graph, use the edges to create a partially ordered set, and then add order relations until you have a full linear order, from which you can trivially get a priority function.  All of this is straightforward once you have figured out which edges to drop.  Conversely given that directed graph and your final priority function, it is easy to figure out which set of edges you had to decide to drop.

Therefore your problem is entirely equivalent to figuring out a minimal set of edges you need to drop from <strike>a</strike>that directed graph to get <strike>a</strike>that directed acyclic graph.  However as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set says, this is a known NP hard problem called the minimum feedback arc set.  *begin update* It is therefore very unlikely that there is a good algorithm for the graphs you can come up with. *end update*

If you need to solve it in practice, I'd suggest going for some sort of greedy algorithm.  It won't always be right, but it will generally give somewhat reasonable results in reasonable time.

**Update:** Moron is correct, I did not prove NP-hard.  However there are good heuristic reasons to believe that the problem is, in fact, NP-hard.  See the comments for more.

Comment: @btilly. I don't think you got the problem. We don't have the priorities from the start, so we can't sort the alphabet by priority as you suggested. Take a look at the example I added.

Comment: @kvark: The example clarifies things substantially.  I didn't get the problem.

Comment: @btilly. Sorry for the initial confusion. After thinking on the problem for a while, it's hard to explain it completely from the start. Thanks for the try, but I would suggest you to remove the answer as it doesn't correspond to the question.

Comment: @kvark: I've updated the answer instead.  The new answer is, unfortunately, that your problem is NP-hard.

Comment: The reduction is done in the opposite direction. Even if correct, all you have shown is that the Feedback arc set problem is _harder_ than the current problem, which does not prove anything about the NP-Hardness of the current problem.

Comment: @Moron: You are correct.  I did not demonstrate NP-hard because you can't generate all graphs.  (You can only generate all graphs that have a path that generates the graph.)  However there is no trouble generating graphs where every node has very high degree and there are a lot of cycles.  Which is exactly the class of graphs that make this problem hard.  It would therefore be very surprising if the problem failed to be NP-hard.

Comment: @btilly. So, finally, is this problem equivalent to Feedback Arc Set? From what I read on wiki it looks to be equivalent, but I don't understand completely the part of the discussion about it being NP-hard or not.

Comment: @kvark: I showed that an efficient solution to the Minimum Feedback Arc Set problem gives an efficient solution to your problem.  However the converse is not necessarily true, because not all possible digraphs can be generated from an array in this manner.  So it is possible that there could be an efficient solution for the digraphs that arise in your problem.  That possibility seems unlikely though.

Comment: @btilly. Oh, I see now. Thank you for the explanation and especially for pointing me to FAS problem. Still, my original problem is not yet covered in detail. Just in case, can you advice some particular FAS searching algorithm that would fit my constraints on E and N ?

Comment: Googling for *minimum feedback arc set heuristic* gives me http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.47.7745&rep=rep1&type=pdf which looks applicable.

Comment: So how do you know "there is no good algorithm to solve it"? If you're going on nothing more than "unlikely", that's something one could have said right at the start. :p

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I did a heck of a lot more than just say, "I dunno how to do it."  I've shown that it is connected to an NP-hard problem, and in particular that you can generate the type of graph where that NP-hard problem is believed to be hardest to solve.  While not in any way a proof, this is pretty strong evidence that this problem is likewise intractable.  Certainly a lot better than just claiming, "Looks unlikely."

Comment: Yes, but this part of the connection (a reduction *to* minimum feedback arc set) was kind of obvious as soon as the problem was stated… it's a reduction in the other direction (*from* a NP-hard problem) that I thought about for quite a while yesterday, and didn't post because I couldn't find one. Anyway apologies; you are right and I accept that a heuristic argument is still better than nothing.

Comment: BTW, for some heuristics that may run fast enough (I'd prefer algorithms proved to be correct but not polynomial-time, but fast enough in practice, over greedy algorithms) — searching for [minimum weight feedback arc set](http://www.google.com/search?q=minimum+(weight+OR+cost)+feedback+arc+set) gives some; in particular this [cstheory.stackexchange thread](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/423/any-fast-algorithm-for-minimum-cost-feedback-arc-set-problem) has some recent results.

Comment: Given that |N| >> |E|, an O(|E|!) solution still might be useful. I'm assuming |N| is irrelevant since the graph representation has at most |E| nodes and |E|_Choose_2 weighted arcs.

Comment: @xan. My `|E|` can be `256` at max. I don't think `256!` will have an acceptable performance. Anyway, just to be sure, are you talking about brute-force approach?

Comment: @kvark Yes, I was thinking of brute-force if |E| is ~12. Nevermind.

Comment: @kvark: If you've already seen it, then you already know the best heuristics for MWFAS, which covers your problem. What else remains but for you to read and implement one of them? :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR. Well, for this question that may be it. I've already implemented a (working) greedy algoritm and now reading the papers pointed out by @user614296. But there is also an [extended version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4981509/607131) of the question.

Answer (score 3):

There's a trivial reduction from Minimum Feedback Arc Set on directed graphs whose arcs can be arranged into an Eulerian path. I quote from http://www14.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/personen/jacob/Publications/JMMN07.pdf :

> To the best of our knowledge, the
>   complexity status of minimum feedback
>   arc set in such graphs is open.
>   However, by a lemma of Newman, Chen,
>   and Lovász [1, Theorem 4], a
>   polynomial algorithm for [this problem]
>   would lead to a 16/9 approximation
>   algorithm for the general minimum
>   feedback arc set problem, improving
>   over the currently best known O(log n
>   log log n) algorithm [2].
>
> 1. Newman, A.: The maximum acyclic subgraph problem and degree-3 graphs.
>      In: Proceedings of the 4th
>      International Workshop on
>      Approximation Algorithms for
>      Combinatorial Optimization Problems,
>      APPROX. LNCS (2001) 147–158
> 2. Even,G.,Naor,J.,Schieber,B.,Sudan,M.:Approximatingminimumfeedbacksets
>      and multi-cuts in directed graphs. In:
>      Proceedings of the 4th International
>      Con- ference on Integer Programming
>      and Combinatorial Optimization. LNCS
>      (1995) 14–28

Comment: @user614296. Thanks for the answer. I'm looking into those articles at the moment.

Comment: @user614296. Where can I find this 16/9 approximation algorithm exacly?