# Find the priority function / alphabet order for extreme higher order elements relation

Tags: algorithm, math

This question is an extension to the [following one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4959719/607131). The difference is that now our function to optimize will have higher order relations between elements:

We have an array of elements `a1,a2,...aN` from an alphabet `E`. Assuming `|N| >> |E|`.

For each symbol of the alphabet we define an unique integer priority = `V(sym)`. Let's define `V{i} := V(symbol(ai))` for the simplicity.

The task is to find a priority function V for which:

```
Count(i)->MIN |   V{i} > V{i+1} <= V{i+2}
```

In other words, I need to find the priorities / permutation of the alphabet for which the number of positions `i`, satisfying the condition `V{i}>V{i+1}<=V{i+2}`, is minimum.

**Maximum required abstraction (low priority for me)**. I guess once the solution model for the [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4959719/607131) is extended to cover the first part of this one, extending it farther (see below) will be easier.

Given a matrix of signs B of size MxK (basically `B[i,j]` is from the set `{<,>,<=,>=}`), find the priority function V for which:

```
Sum(for all j in range [1,M]) {Count(i)}->EXTREMUM | V{i} B[j,1] V{i+1} B[j,2] ... B[j,K] V{i+K}
```

As an example, find the priority function `V`, for which the number of `i`, satisfying `V{i}<V{i+1}<V{i+2}` or `V{i}>V{i+1}>V{i+2}`, is minimum.

Comment: wondering what is the motivation for this problem?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod. My BWT sorting algoritm uses an improved 2-nd order Itoh-Tanaka version as a base. Hence, it requires to sort directly only those substrings that satisfy condition `S{i}>S{i+1}<=S{s+2}`. Now I'm trying to reorder the alphabet in a most effective way to reduce the amount of sub-strings that need to be sorted directly, greatly increasing performance. I've also developed a generalization of Itoh-Tanaka methods for higher orders, that is why the second part of the question exists. So, well, there is a pretty strong motivation behind this :)

Comment: Unless you have some reason to believe otherwise, I'd expect any problem of this type to be NP-hard.

Comment: @btilly. I don't require an exact solution. Any greedy algoritm giving reasonable results would be sufficient.

Comment: Ah, well in that case, write down a random permutation.  Then try swapping elements and accept a swap when it improves your permutation.  You have a solution when you reach a local minimum.  Repeat the process any number of desired times and accept the best minimum.

Comment: @btilly. Sounds pretty brute-force :) If that's your proposal, why not writing it in an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: That is my proposal, but the size felt like more of a comment than a solid answer.  You might get more ideas from looking for a genetic algorithm.

Comment: @btilly. Please, make it an answer still. Do you have any particular links of genetic algorithms applied to NP-hard problems like mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition is that all variations on this problem will prove to be NP-hard.  So I'd begin looking for heuristics that produce reasonable answers.  This may involve some trial and error.

A simplistic approach is to write down a possible permutation.  And then try possible swaps until you've arrived at a local minimum.  Try several times, and pick the best answer.

Simulated annealing provides a more sophisticated version of this approach, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing for a description.  It may take some experimentation to find a set of parameters that seems to converge relatively well.

Another idea is to look for a genetic algorithm.  Based on a quick Google search it looks like the standard way to do this is to try to turn an NP-complete problem into a SAT problem, and then use a genetic algorithm on that problem.  This approach would require turning this into a SAT problem in some reasonable way.  Unfortunately it is not obvious to me how one would go about doing this reduction.  Indeed in the first version that you had, your problem was closely connected to a classic NP-hard problem.  The fact that it is labeled NP-hard rather than NP-complete is evidence that people haven't found a good way to transform it into a SAT problem.  So if it isn't obvious how to turn the simple version into a SAT problem, then you are unlikely to convert the hard problem either.

But you could still try some variation on genetic algorithms.  Mutation is pretty simple, just swap some elements around.  One way to combine elements would be to take 3 permutations and use quicksort to find the combination as follows: take a random pivot, and then use "majority wins" to bucket elements into bigger and smaller.  Sort each half in the same way.

I'm sorry that I can't just give you an approach and say, "This should work."  You've got what looks like an open-ended research project, and the best I can do is give you some ideas about things you can try that might work reasonably well.